# No visual response (highlight) on touching a menu item

Tags: android, xml

There is not visual response to selecting a menu item. For example, within the menu, on clicking settings, the settings activity just opens up without any visual response from the clicking the settings item. How do I solve this. Also, how do I add a ripple using a 3rd party library?[This is the library I'm using](https://github.com/traex/RippleEffect), and I've managed to add ripple to other buttons, but it just doesn't work on menu items.

Here's the code for menu:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
app:showAsAction = "ifRoom">

<item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
      android:title="@string/action_settings"
      android:orderInCategory="1"/>

<item android:id = "@+id/Quit"
    android:title = "@string/quit_app"
    app:showAsAction="never"
    android:orderInCategory="2"/>

</menu>
```

Comment: What do you mean by visual response? That the entry is highlighted? Whats you code for the menu?

Comment: @Mainz007 Yes, I meant it's not highlighted. I just posted the code. Please check.

Comment: That's just the XML. Can you also post the java-code for the menu?

Comment: @Mainz007 But I haven't made any UI changes from the java code .

Comment: ok. I just see, that you have `showAsAction` in the `menu` Do you maybe wanna have it in the  `item` action_settings? I don't know if it solves your problem, but if you didn't change anything in the code then this is the only thing I can think of.

Comment: @Mainz007 damn, I'm not sure how that got into menu. Anyways, no, that didn't solve the problem.